# ggplot problem; code is plotting lines as some very strange bars. Why is this?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I'm having a bit of a problem  when it comes to plotting some data from a dataframe. It seems to treat multiple series as being the same line. Does anyone know why this is?

Dataframe code to create df:

```
df <- read.table(text="Date     Item            Purchased
01/01/08 Fruit              48
01/01/08 Confectionary      42
01/01/08 Appliance          11
01/06/08 Confectionary      16
01/06/08 Fruit              19
01/06/08 Appliance          50", header=TRUE)
```

My code to plot data:

```
test_df <- ggplot(df)+geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=Purchased, color=Item, group = 1),size=8)+
  theme(title=element_text(size=10),panel.background = element_rect(fill='white'),legend.position='top')+geom_hline(yintercept = 0,color="white")

test_df
```

This result of my plot:[image]

I'd like to plot some time series of this data; one line for 'Fruit', one for 'Confectionary' and one for 'Appliance'. Does anyone know why it's doing this?

*EDIT: Adding x=lubridate::mdy(Date) produces thee following result:
[image]

Comment: You need to convert your date values to proper date values rather than just strings. Try `geom_line(aes(x=lubridate::mdy(Date), y=Purchased, color=Item),size=8)` for example. Or just get the group to the values you are actually grouping on, which is Item: `geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=Purchased, color=Item, group = Item),size=8)` Otherwise if you just set `group=1` then it will try to connect all points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to MrFlick, the issue was including the group=1